# Google Map event listener only work first time with colorbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, colorbox

I've added a listener in the google map info window to open a colorbox with some information about that marker.

My problem is that colorbox works only for the first marker I click. For example: I click on a marker and opens the colorbox, if I close this marker and is opening another, the console displays the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).colorbox is not a function
```

however if I reopen the same marker to open the first time, it does not display error, and again opens the information by colorbox.

any marker I click on first when the page loads, will show the information, however, if i close and try another marker, without refreshing the page, will not open and display the error

the markers are being populated via mysql and php.

my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 var icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://www.yolps.com.br/imagens/ic_mapaok.png',
 new google.maps.Size(50,50), 
 new google.maps.Point(0,0),
 new google.maps.Point(0,0),
 new google.maps.Size(50,50));
 var center = null;
 var map = null;
 var currentPopup;
 var geocoder;
 var pinColor = "FE7569";
    var pinImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|" + pinColor,
        new google.maps.Size(21, 34),
        new google.maps.Point(0,0),
        new google.maps.Point(10, 34));
    var pinShadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_shadow",
        new google.maps.Size(40, 37),
        new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        new google.maps.Point(12, 35));
 var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
 function addMarker(lat, lng, info) {
 var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
 bounds.extend(pt);
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
 position: pt,
 icon: icon,
 map: map
 });
 var popup = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
 content: info
 //maxWidth: 300

 });
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
 if (currentPopup != null) {
 currentPopup.close();
 currentPopup = null;
 }
 popup.open(map, marker);
 currentPopup = popup;
 });
 google.maps.event.addListener(popup, "closeclick", function() {
 map.panTo(center);
 currentPopup = null;
 });

//FUNCTION TO CALL COLORBOX

 google.maps.event.addListener(popup, "domready", function() {

                $(".inline").colorbox({inline:true, width:"1026px"});
                $('.inline').click(function(){
   var data_id = $(this).data('id');
   $('#idvalue').html(""+data_id);
 $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: "view/detalhes.php?eventoid="+data_id,
         success: function(data) {
             $('#evento2').html(data);
         }
     }); 
});
 });
 $.colorbox.close();

 }


 function initMap() {
     geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    if(!!navigator.geolocation) {
/*var map;
var mapOptions = {
                    zoom: 13,

                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

                };
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions); */
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
 center: new google.maps.LatLng(0,0),
 zoom: 2,
 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
 mapTypeControl: false,
 mapTypeControlOptions: {
 style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR
 },
 navigationControl: true,
 navigationControlOptions: {
 style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL 
 }
 });

 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {

                    var geolocate = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
                    var accu = position.coords.accuracy / 30;
        geocoder.geocode({'latLng': geolocate}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      console.log(results)
        if (results[1]) {
         //formatted address
         //alert(results[0].formatted_address)
        //find country name
             for (var i=0; i<results[0].address_components.length; i++) {
            for (var b=0;b<results[0].address_components[i].types.length;b++) {

            //there are different types that might hold a city admin_area_lvl_1 usually does in come cases looking for sublocality type will be more appropriate
                if (results[0].address_components[i].types[b] == "locality") {
                    //this is the object you are looking for
                    city= results[0].address_components[i];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
                    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        map: map,
                        position: geolocate,
                        content:'<h3 class="texto"> Você esta em '+ city.short_name +'!</h3>'


                    });
        }else {
          alert("No results found");
      }
      } else {
        alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
      } 
      });
                    /*var marker1 = new google.maps.GeolocationMarker({
                         icon: pinImage
                         });*/
                    var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
                          center: geolocate,
                          radius: accu,
                          map: map,
                          fillColor: 'rgb(161, 142, 0)',
                          fillOpacity: 0.3,
                          strokeColor: 'rgb(255, 204, 0)',
                          strokeOpacity: 0.7
                        });
                    map.fitBounds(circle.getBounds());
                    map.setCenter(geolocate);




            });
 }          else {
                document.getElementById('google_canvas').innerHTML = 'No Geolocation Support.';
            }

 <?php 
 require_once 'connect.php';
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * from localizacoes WHERE dataevento >= ((now()- INTERVAL 1 DAY) - INTERVAL 3 HOUR)");
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
 $r =  explode( ',', $row['posicao'] );
 $name=$row['nome'];
 $lat = $r[0];
 $lon = $r[1];
 $desc=$row['descricao'];
 $image = '<a class="inline" href="#inline_content" data-id="'.$row['id'].'" ><img class="foto" src="http://www.yolps.com.br/uploadedimages/'.$row['imagem'].'"/></a>';
// $image = '<a href="http://yolps.com.br/evento/'.$row['id'].'/'.$row['nome'].'" alt="Clique para detalhes" target="_blank"><img class="foto" src="http://www.yolps.com.br/uploadedimages/'.$row['imagem'].'"/></a>';
 $dataevento = explode( '-', $row['dataevento'] );
 $ano = $dataevento[0];
 $mes = $dataevento[1];
 $dia = $dataevento[2];
 //$d = nl2br($desc);
 $de = str_replace("\n", "</br>", $desc);
 echo ("addMarker($lat, $lon,'<h1>$name</h1>$image');\n");
 }
 ?>
 //center = bounds.getCenter();

 //google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);

 }
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
 //setTimeout(function() { initMap(); },5000);

 </script>
    </head>
    <script>
    function refresh(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        setTimeout(function() { initMap(); },2000);

});
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Not your problem, but MarkerImage has been deprecated for a while now.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: try this:http://main.xfiddle.com/60abc423/map.php

Comment: take a look in my website [link here](http://yolps.com.br/#mapa)...i have some markers and they show the images correctly, but when i click first time on image inside the marker, it opens the colorbox, but when i click to close and try to open another marker, show the error and dont open the colorbox...

Comment: any help? my minimal, complete and readable example isnt  good to help? just look at live site http://www.yolps.com.br